# C++: how to set up an "Item" class correctly

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am currently making a 2D platform game engine however I can't seem to create an elegant design for my "Item" class.

What do I mean by item: anything the player can hold in his/her inventory e.g. iron or a healing potion

How it fits into my project - 3 classes deal with "Item"s:

1. The "Inventory" class
2. The "Level" class (stores the location of dropped "Item"s)
3. The "Player_Equipment_Slots" class. This is where the issue manifests:

   ```
   #include "Globals.h"
   #include "Item.h"

   class Player_Equipment_Slots
   {
   public:
   Player_Equipment_Slots();
   Player_Equipment_Slots(Player& playerObj);
   virtual ~Player_Equipment_Slots();

   // return: the item that was already equipped, if there was one already equipped
   Item equipItem(Item itemToEquip);

   Attributes getTotalAttributes() const { return totalAttributes; }

   private:

   // applies passive effects equipment may have to the player and removes any existing one (called by equipItem)
   void updateEquipmentEffects(Item& newEquipment, Item& oldEquipment);
   // subtracts the stats of the old item and adds the new items stats (called by equipItem)
   void updateTotalAttributes();

   Item necklaceSlot;
   Item ringSlot1;
   Item ringSlot2;
   Item trinket1;
   Item trinket2;

   Attributes totalAttributes;

   Player& playerObj;
   };
   ```

The problem: The Item class has two constructors

```
    ItemDetails();
    ItemDetails(std::string itemName, itemType itmType, rarity itemRarity, Coordinate itemIconCoord, std::string effect);
```

Ideally I would want to get rid of the default constructor because an item should only be created using the second constructor however if I do that, the Player_Equipment_Slots class will understandibly complain at compile time because the-

```
    Item necklaceSlot;
    Item ringSlot1;
    Item ringSlot2;
    Item trinket1;
    Item trinket2;
```

objects need to invoke a default constructor.

**The question**: how would I redesign these classes so that my Item class does not have a default constructor but other classes (such as Player_Equipment_Slots) can store private Item objects.
I understand this could be easily achieved with pointers however I want to avoid using the 'new' keyword every time a new item is created. Perhaps there is also a way I can use pointers without using the 'new' keyword however I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

use inheritance, the Item are for the different class of usage (is just a recommendation ) ,  if you don't want to use default constructor just delete it `Item()=delete` or put in the **private** section of the class.